# Can't remove bullet points from UL list with Icons

Tags: css, list, icons, html-lists

I have a list with Icons here:

http://punky-monkey.co.uk/chalet6/our-chalet/

```
<ul class="keyfeatures">
    <li id="sleeps14">Sleeps 14</li>
    <li id="hottub">Outdoor Hot Tub</li>
    <li id="fire">Log Fire</li>
    <li id="terrace">South Facing Terrace</li>
    <li id="outdoorterrace">Outdoor Terrace</li>
    <li id="coffee">Bean to Cup Coffee Machine</li>
    <li id="wine">Honesty Bar</li>
    <li id="tv">Freeview TV</li>
    <li id="games">Games Console</li>
    <li id="ipod">iPod Dock</li>
    <li id="wifi">Free Wi-Fi</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.keyfeatures li {list-style-type:none; vertical-align:top; margin-left:30px; list-style:none;}

ul #sleeps14 { list-style-image: url('http://punky-monkey.co.uk/chalet6/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/bed.png'); }
ul #hottub { list-style-image: url('http://punky-monkey.co.uk/chalet6/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/hottub.png'); }
ul #fire { list-style-image: url('http://punky-monkey.co.uk/chalet6/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/fire.png'); }
ul #terrace { list-style-image: url('http://punky-monkey.co.uk/chalet6/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/sun.png'); }
ul #outdoorterrace { list-style-image: url('http://punky-monkey.co.uk/chalet6/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/lounger.png'); }
ul #coffee { list-style-image: url('http://punky-monkey.co.uk/chalet6/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/beans.png'); }
ul #wine { list-style-image: url('http://punky-monkey.co.uk/chalet6/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/wine.png'); }
ul #tv { list-style-image: url('http://punky-monkey.co.uk/chalet6/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/tv.png'); }
ul #games { list-style-image: url('http://punky-monkey.co.uk/chalet6/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/games.png'); }
ul #ipod { list-style-image: url('http://punky-monkey.co.uk/chalet6/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/ipod.png'); }
ul #wifi { list-style-image: url('http://punky-monkey.co.uk/chalet6/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/wifiicon2020.png'); }
```

I want to remove the bullet points from the list and only have the icons, I have tried putting list-style-type:none pretty much everywhere - something is overwriting it.

Can anyone help? Thanks, Warren

Comment: [Seems to work to me](http://jsbin.com/akejon/1/edit). Check in your browser's developer tools what are the applied styles.

Comment: first just test a normal li {list-style-type: none; ) instead of the one with the class.

Comment: For more efficiency, change `ul #sleeps14` to `#sleeps14`.

Comment: BTW, I hope you don't have those id used more than once.

Comment: works fine for me too by the way.

Comment: Please, next time build a minimal working example (might be at http://jsbin.com) demonstrating your problem. This question can be solved by looking at your site but we don't like to do distant debug.

Comment: ok thanks dystroy, first time I've used the site for help so thanks for that, you were a big help and have it working as I want to now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is being overridden by the following CSS

```
ul li:after
{
    border-left: solid 3px #fe6500 !important;      
}
```

Make that apply to only a specific list if you need that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the the CSS inline `ul li:after` declaration. Those are shadowing the styles in styles.css.

```
ul li:after {
    border-left: 3px solid #FE6500 !important;
}
```